# how to redirect a react component on set timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, settimeout

I have a quiz application that I am creating and I have a Question component. Each time the question component renders, I want to start a 60 second timer. If the user does not answer or leaves the application, after 60 seconds I want to redirect them to the home page where the next user would be able to start the quiz from the beginning.

I also had another question about the `componentWillMount()` function. I have that same question componenent that has 6 different instances or ('questions') as you would say. When i go from question 1 to question 2, the `componentWillMount()` function does not refire. It only fires on the first render of that component, even though they are different instances. I need to make sure that timer restarts on each components rendering.
What would be the best way of doing this? Is it best to use the `props.history.push('/')` .

```
componentWillMount(){
    setTimeout(() => { 
        console.log('this ran') 
        this.props.history.push('/');
}, 60000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe there is a problem with setTimeout which purpose is to trigger event once, so you can try with setInterval which purpose is execute function unlimited number of times.

Maybe you can check more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934781/set-timeout-to-react-function).